# Is there any method or options to select uppercase/lowercase field like ABC/abc in Dataframe of pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, select, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to get result of select method in pyspark, but there are some error.
I made a Dataframe which have two fields(`ABC`, `abc`). After that I use select method of pyspark to get `ABC` field *data* (not `abc` field). 
But there are some error.

How can I get ABC field data?

```
+---+---+
|ABC|abc|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

This is my example code.

```py
df=_sqlCtx.createDataFrame([{'ABC':1,'abc':2}])
df.show()

df2 = df.select("ABC")
df2.show()
```

> AnalysisException: u"Reference 'ABC' is ambiguous, could be: ABC,
>   ABC.;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable case-sensitivity for this:

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([{'ABC':1,'abc':2}])
spark_session.sql('set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true')
df.select("ABC").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+
|ABC|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```